# Django категории и подкатегории

Tags: python, django

Помогите разобраться что делаю не так. Есть модель:

```
class DiaryCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default='Новый дневник', max_length=150, db_index=True, verbose_name='Название дневника')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор дневника')
    cat_img = models.ImageField(default='diary_img/diary.jpeg', upload_to='diary_img',
                                verbose_name='Изображение категории')
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Дата обновления')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Дневник'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Дневники'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('diary_cat_detail', kwargs={'cat_pk': self.pk})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        img = Image.open(self.cat_img.path)
        output_size = (500, 500)
        img.thumbnail(output_size)
        img.save(self.cat_img.path)


class DiarySubCatigory(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(DiaryCategory, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               verbose_name='Дневник')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Название категории')
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Категория дневника'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории дневника'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('diary_subcat_detail', kwargs={'main_pk': self.parent.pk, 'sub_pk': self.pk})
```

При создании подкатегории вываливается в ошибку Generic detail view DiarySubCategoryCreateView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

В файле urls.py

```
 path('<int:cat_pk>/', DiaryCategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='diary_cat_detail'),
    path('create/', DiaryCategoryCreateView.as_view(), name='diare_cat_create'),
    path('<int:cat_pk>/update/', DiaryCategoryUpdateView.as_view(), name='diare_cat_update'),
    path('<int:cat_pk>/delete/', DiaryCategoryDeleteView.as_view(), name='diare_cat_delete'),

    path('<int:cat_pk>/sub_add/', DiarySubCategoryCreateView.as_view(), name='diary_subcat_create'),
    path('<int:main_pk>/<int:sub_pk>/', DiarySubCategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='diary_subcat_detail'),
```

Во вьюхе:

```
class DiarySubCategoryCreateView(CreateView):
    model = DiarySubCatigory
    fields = ['name']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance = self.get_object().parent.name
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('diary_cat_detail', kwargs={'cat_pk': self.get_object().id})
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему. Неправильно передавал `form.instance`.
Правильный вариант:

```
form.instance.parent = DiaryCategory.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['cat_pk'])
```